# OG: Type 'website' cause internal error occurred while linting the URL

Tags: facebook, debugging, web, facebook-opengraph

Wordpress
Facebook plugin

Whenever I have "OG: Type 'website'", the facebook debug linter comes back with

> Error Linting URL: An internal error occurred while linting the URL.

[Link to debug](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.shotgunmyferrari.com)

If I change 'website' to 'blog' in plugins/facebook/open-graph-protocol.php, it works. It just doesn't like 'website'.  Not sure why the default type of 'website' from the official facebook plugin doesn't work on my site.

Thanks guys, spent a few late nights (5am last night, 4am tonight) playing around with OG.
-Matt

ps. This all lead from when I post, it goes to my group wall, but on my timeline it shows under "Recent activity - Molson published test on ShotgunMyFerrari.com." but not on my personal wall.

Comment: It has something do with with the URL and the debugger is coming back with Response Code: 206. I made a dev site local on my computer and used LocalTunnet to port it out to the web, and the debugger worked. So I know the wordpress theme and code is correct.

Really stumped on this one.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar problem on my site, but i had an object created in my facebook app by the name "website".

I had to manually change the og:type to myAppName:website in the plugin file plugins/facebook/open-graph-protocol.php and it works.

But still wondering why the default thing did not work. Can anybody throw some more light on the issue?